# How can I get a subset in a 2-column dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following *Data Frame*

```py
df = pd.DataFrame ([
    ['1', None, '6', None, '11', None, '19', None], 
    ['2', 'a', '7', 'a', '12', 'b', '20', 'f'], 
    ['3', 'b', '8', 'a', '13', 'b', nan, nan], 
    ['4 ',' b ',' 9 ',' a ',' 14 ',' b ', nan, nan], 
    [' 5 ',' d ',' 10 ',' c ',' 15 ',' b ', nan, nan], 
    [nan, nan, nan, nan,' 16 ',' h ', nan, nan], 
    [nan, nan, nan, nan,' 17 ',' h ', nan, nan] , 
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, '18', 'h', nan, nan]
])
```

[image]

And I want to order my data to be the following form, I am using the function

```py
df2 = df.groupby("1_a")["1.0"].apply(list)
```

But I want to apply it in to all columns

[image]

the idea is that I have a `_DataFrame_` like the following

[image]

Comment: You want `1_a`, `2_a`, `3_a` etc... as different DataFrames or as one DataFrame with different columns? Can you clarify the question? It is not clear

Comment: all in the same DataFrame, but in different DataFrame is also a possibility